# How to get n unique numbers uniformly from a given range?

Tags: python, numpy, range, uniform-distribution

I have a integer range [0, Z). I need to obtain n (where n <= Z) random numbers from this range, but they have to be unique. So I know I can just code up rejection sampling to do this, but I'm wondering if there's a one line python function that can do this for me?

Comment: Are you talking about integers or floats? How big is Z?

Comment: @mozway Sorry, integers. Just edited the OP. Z is dynamic depending on the input, but I would say it's O(10^6)

Comment: Then go with `np.random.choice` without replacement as suggested below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not use random sampling without replacement

```py
import numpy as np

n = 25
a = range(26)
out = np.random.choice(a, size=n, replace=False)
```

```
len(np.unique(out))
>>>25
```

Comment: ahh. Wasn't aware that `np.random` had a without replacement option

Comment: makes thing easy :)